# Writing to the event log with hierarchy

Tags: c#, event-log, event-viewer

I know there are a lot of topics about writing to the event viewer on SO, but I didn't find what I need.

I have the following code to create a new Event Log Category in the event Viewer:

```
string sSource = "MyWebService";
string sLog = "My Application";
string sMsg = "Error Message Goes here";

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
{ EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog); }
```

This works as expected and in the Event Viewer, I have the following output:

[image]

So, writing to the event viewer is not a problem, but **the problem occurs** when I want to create some hierarchy in the logs.

So, let's assume that I've written an application that consists out of various components:

```
- MVC
- Web API
- Windows Service
```

Then in the Event Viewer, I want to create a dictionary that contains all those elements just as Microft does:

[image]

This means I would like to have an output that looks like:

```
- Application (directory)
    - MVC (directory)
        - Others (logs)
    - Web API (directory)
        - Demo (logs)
    - Windows Service (directory)
        - Authentication (logs)
```

I've tried to do the following:

```
string sSource = "MyWebService";
string sLog = "My Application";
string sMsg = "Error Message Goes here";

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
{ EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog); }

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sLog))
{ EventLog.CreateEventSource(sLog, "Web Service"); }
```

But of course, this didn't work.

Anyone knows a how to create a hierarchical structure in the Event Viewer?

Important to say: I like to have full control over my code, so I don't wan't to use any third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want you need to use Event Tracing for Windows (ETW). In .NET you can use the [EventSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) class but there is a more up to date NuGet package that I suggest you use: [Microsoft EventSource Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource). There is also a NuGet package with samples which should provide a good starting point if you are new to ETW.

In addition to creating code that writes to the event log you need to create a manifest and an associated resource DLL. The NuGet package has a tool that automates this process based on the log events that you have created in code. You then need to register the event source using the [wevtutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx) command line tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as my question states, I would like to have control over my code, meaning I would like to avoid using packages. I can use packages later, but first I want to know how it works. :-)

Comment: @Complexity: Well, then good luck using P/Invoke to call the native ETW API. I had a peek at the `EventSource` code and it is pretty complex. To do what you want you still need to use ETW and here is a link to the API documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hmm, don't like to do P/Invoke, so I might go with the nuget package.

Comment: @Complexity: The `EventSource` class is also part of the .NET framework. However, the NuGet package contains a newer and presumeably better version of the library. Expect more and more Microsoft libraries to be shipped via NuGet instead of in the framework.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the package. Since it's from Microsft, I don't have big troubles to use it :-)